# xcode swift4 how do I change the page in viewdidload

Tags: swift, xcode

I cannot use segue on viewDidLoad.

I already check the segue is worded on another func.

When load the view check some condition then change view this is what I want.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "go" , sender: self)
}
```

Comment: On `viewDidLoad()` your view controller is not part of the hierarchy yet, do it in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: More specifically, why would you want to perform a segue in the `viewDidLoad` method? For 99% of all use cases, it defeats the point of having this view in first place. Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve by doing this and why you wouldn't present the "go" view by default instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace **viewDidLoad** to **viewDidAppear** solved my problem

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "go" , sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to push your view controller on view did load then just use this code.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "your_StoryBoard", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC_Identifier") as! TargerViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

OR
You can set the target viewcontroller as root viewcontroller by check any condition.

Hope it will helps you out.

Answer (score -1):

i prefer that don't use segue use as below

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboard", bundle: nil)
 let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier") as! Your ViewController
 self.present(VC, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

user this for redirect from One VC To Another VC